# Postfix: virtual dovecot users + catch all to script

Tags: postfix, dovecot

In my postfix configuration, I'm forwarding (PIPE) all emails to a script. But I also have some virtual mailboxes in dovecot that should be prioritized.

main.cf

```
...
# Handle mailboxes from database 
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhosts
virtual_transport = dovecot
local_transport = virtual
local_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-maps.cf

# fallback to mailinglists when users are not database
fallback_transport = ScriptTransporter
...
```

The fallback should be a catch-all transport for all aliases not in the virtual mailbox, but the received mails will never reach the fallback_transport but will always end in a `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table` error

EDIT:
The (Symfony) script does check on aliases itself and stores these emails in a database, as these aliases change dynamically, I would like to check them via the script itself rather than using postfix to have more flexibility and control.

Is a configuration like this possible in another way?
Thanks

Comment: You can imitate what `fallback_relay` does for `local` because you have access to the list of virtual mailboxes - similar to your virtual-mailbox-maps you could also have a query to be used for `transport_maps` (no-op for all existing addresses, plus static default for your script).

Comment: I would usually prefer *not* receiving crap at all, and then still prefer remapping those recipients to something descriptively named (an alias *all unmatched -> fallback@domain.example*) instead of passing them to their transport straight away, but which solution is truly better depends a bit on context. Mind editing your question and saying *why* you would want to receive mail to addresses that your system considers nonexistant?